# Error EADDRNOTAVAIL al levantar app node

Tags: nodejs, pm2

Estoy tratando de levantar una app node con pm2 en una maquina virtual de windows, el problema que al hacerlo me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe como solucionar este error se lo agradeceria

Comment: Al parecer ya hay algo corriendo en el puerto 3000. Posiblemente otra instancia de tu misma app que no está usando pm2. Para descartar has un "PM2 list" y un "PM logs" y pega aqui los resultados. Como texto, no como imagen por favor.

Comment: syscall: 'listen',
address: '13.90.92.134',
port: 3000
 }
 Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 13.90.92.134:3000
 at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1468:21)
 at listenInCluster (node:net:1533:12) at doListen (node:net:1682:7)
 at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
 code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
 errno: -4090,
 syscall: 'listen',
 address: '13.90.92.134',
 port: 3000
 }

Comment: Edite la pregunta para agregar el pm2 list

Comment: Revisa si alguna de estas respuestas te sirve:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583562/how-to-kill-a-process-running-on-particular-port-in-linux

Comment: Esto trabajando sobre un servidor de windows y no hay ningun proceso que esté ocupando mi puerto 3000

Comment: Ok. Entonces, intenta subir el puerto por encima del puerto 5000. En algúnas ocasiones, el firewall de windows bloquea todos los puertos mas bajos  que eso. Si esto no fuciona. Intenta correr una terminal con permisos de administrador. Si funciona, posiblemente el usuario que estés usando no tenga permisos.

Comment: estuve haciendo pruebas y la app solo me ha dejado utilizar la ip 127.0.0.1 la interna del equipo, como podría permitir otras ip? por ejemplo la que necesito la 13.90.92.134 (es la ip de la maquina virtual de azure donde está alojado mi app node)

Comment: Eso ya cambia la cosa. Si estas usando azure, en su documentación, te tiene que asignar un puerto de salida (de eso no estoy seguro). Si usas un servidor dedicado (donde tu puedes controlar todas las configuraciones) pues necesitas abrir puertos en el firewall.

Comment: logré solucionarlo, tan solo necesitaba modificar mi configuracion de mi index.js del servidor para que escuchara mas direcciones ip y no solo la interna por defecto (127.0.0.1) es decir modificar la línea: 
server.listen(port)  la cual anteriormente la tenía como server.listen(port, host);

Comment: Excelente. Sería bueno que publiques la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta.